# Regular expression with repeating groups in Java Pattern

Tags: java, regex

Lets say I have the following strings:

```
mya!phaNum3rics-456-456-lll
zzzz-6a6-6a6-lll
vvvv-4-4-lll
```

These are considered matches because "second" and "third" group repeat, and last group ends with `lll`. What regex would allows for any character sequence in the second and third "group".

How much different if the following is also considered a match?

```
zasdfdf-zadezz-6a6-6a6-lll
```

"third to last group" repeats with "second to last group" and ends with "group" `lll`.

Comment: You are looking for backreferences: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html#backref.

Comment: Yes, I will try  backreferences. Never new this existed, especially within Java regex engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
-([^-]+)-\1-lll$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EnpNbT/1)

- `-` - a hyphen
- `([^-]+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more symbols other than `-`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\1` - a [**backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to the text captured into Group 1
- `-lll` - a substring of literal characters
- `$`  - end of string.

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/IX7FqI):

```
String str = "mya!phaNum3rics-456-456-lll";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("-([^-]+)-\\1-lll$");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0) + " matched!");
}
```

A variation of the same regex for use with `.matches`:

```
if (str.matches(".*-([^-]+)-\\1-lll")) {
    System.out.println(str + " matched!");
}
```